# Add reference to DCOM server in C#, without type library or IDispatch

Tags: c#, dcom

I am currently working on a DCOM client/server application pair. The DCOM server is in C++, whilst the client is to be implented with C#. What I want to do is add a reference to my DCOM server, which is met with the following error:

> A reference to "server.exe" can't be added, Please make sure that the file
>   is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

Accessing the server from a C++ test client is not a problem.

I don't need the DCOM server to be accessed from VBA, so the objects exposed by the DCOM server derive directly from `IUnknown` instead of `IDispatch`, neither does the server have a type library. Also, as far as I know, type libraries don't marshal arrays correctly, which is a key requirement. The server is instead accessed using a proxy dll. Alternatively, I tried my C# project to reference said dll, which returns the same error.

Is it possible to solve the reference problem without using IDispatch or TLB?, Is the problem caused by not using a type library at all?

The test client as requested by @HansPassant

```
            CoInitialize(NULL);
            HRESULT hr = CoInitializeSecurity(NULL, -1 , NULL, NULL ,RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CONNECT, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, NULL ,EOAC_NONE ,NULL);
            CLSID clsid;
            hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"hcps.uitvoering.drawingplanning", &clsid);
            COSERVERINFO si;
            ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(COSERVERINFO));
            si.pwszName = L"localhost";
            IClassFactory* pFactory;
            hr = CoGetClassObject(clsid, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, &si, IID_IClassFactory , (LPVOID*)&pFactory);
            if (hr != S_OK)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            IDrawingPlanningServer * pServer = NULL;
            hr = pFactory->CreateInstance(NULL,  IID_PPV_ARGS(&pServer));
            if (hr == S_OK)
            {
                CClient client;             
                hr = pServer->LogOn(&client);
                IEntry* pEntry;
                hr = pServer->CreateEntry(&pEntry);
                hr = pEntry->Save();
                pEntry->Release();
                hr = pServer->LogOff();
                pServer->Release();
            }
            pFactory->Release();
            CoUninitialize();
            system("pause");
```

and IClient, which serves as a callback interface:

```
class CClient : public IClient
{
public:

STDMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID riid, LPVOID* ppvObject)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    if (NULL == ppvObject)
    {
        hr = E_POINTER;
    }
    else
    {
        hr = E_NOINTERFACE;
        *ppvObject = NULL;  
        if ((riid == IID_IUnknown) || (riid == IID_IClient))
        {
            *ppvObject = static_cast<CClient*>(this);
            hr = S_OK;
        }
    }
    return hr;
}
    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef()
    {
        return 1;
    }
    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release()
    {
        return 1;
    }
    STDMETHODIMP New(IEntry* entry)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }
    STDMETHODIMP Update(IEntry* entry)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }
    STDMETHODIMP Delete(IEntry* entry)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }
};
```

Comment: Don't keep facts you know a secret, what does that C++ program look like?

Comment: It's just a regular out of process server, of which i have written quite a score. What does a DCOM server look like? It registers an IClassFactory object on first invocation, which then facilitates creating COM objects through it's CreateInstance method. Nothing spectacular...

Comment: The test program, not the server.